# How to know if currency pair is going up with COT(commitment of traders) Analysis?

Tags: foreign-exchange

Some `forex` (foreign exchange) traders read the `COT` (Commitment of traders) report issued by `CFTC` (http://www.cftc.gov), to understand in which way the currency pair (Eg: `EUR/USD`) is heading and how much the `large speculators` hold currency positions and how much they closed.

But, it contains only the data of single currency (`EUR` etc), not a pair (`EUR/USD` etc).

Eg: Following is the latest report issued by `CFTC`

`EURO FX - CHICAGO MERCANTILE EXCHANGE`
`Commitments of Traders - Futures Only, July 03, 2017`

```
-------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
     :   Total  :                        Reportable Positions                                :   Nonreportable
     :----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------     Positions
     :   Open   :           Non-Commercial       :     Commercial      :       Total         :
     : Interest :   Long   :  Short   : Spreading:   Long   :  Short   :   Long   :  Short   :   Long   :  Short
-------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
     :          : (CONTRACTS OF EUR 125,000)                                                 :
     :          :                                                                            :
All  :   422,496:   185,925    108,461     15,675    144,260    244,301    345,860    368,437:    76,636     54,059
Old  :   422,496:   185,925    108,461     15,675    144,260    244,301    345,860    368,437:    76,636     54,059
Other:         0:         0          0          0          0          0          0          0:         0          0
     :          :                                                                            :
     :          :          Changes in Commitments from: June 27, 2017                        :
     :    21,936:     6,254    -12,515      1,255      8,126     32,662     15,635     21,402:     6,301        534
     :          :                                                                            :
     :          :    Percent of Open Interest Represented by Each Category of Trader         :
All  :     100.0:      44.0       25.7        3.7       34.1       57.8       81.9       87.2:      18.1       12.8
Old  :     100.0:      44.0       25.7        3.7       34.1       57.8       81.9       87.2:      18.1       12.8
Other:     100.0:       0.0        0.0        0.0        0.0        0.0        0.0        0.0:       0.0        0.0
     :          :                                                                            :
     :# Traders :              Number of Traders in Each Category                            :
All  :       250:        97         57         40         60         65        175        145:
Old  :       250:        97         57         40         60         65        175        145:
Other:         0:         0          0          0          0          0          0          0:
     :----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
     :             Percent of Open Interest Held by the Indicated Number of the Largest Traders
     :                          By Gross Position                       By Net Position
     :               4 or Less Traders     8 or Less Traders     4 or Less Traders     8 or Less Traders
     :                 Long:     Short       Long      Short:      Long      Short       Long      Short
     :----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
All  :                 22.8       31.3       31.8       44.1       22.5       31.3       31.4       43.7
Old  :                 22.8       31.3       31.8       44.1       22.5       31.3       31.4       43.7
Other:                  0.0        0.0        0.0        0.0        0.0        0.0        0.0        0.0
```

I can see that the `Non-commercial` investors have `185,925 long positions` while they only hold `108,461 short positions`. But it's only the single currency of `EURO`. But how to tell that a currency pair is going up (or down)?

**P.S**: I apologize previously I have posted the wrong report. Now I have edited and replaced the correct report with single currency.

Answer (score 1):

That tells you it's a cross rate - `EURO FX/BRITISH POUND XRATE` so it's a cross of the euro vs the British pound.

What you have to do for each of these is go to the futures market, which is specified in the report

```
EURO FX/BRITISH POUND XRATE - CHICAGO MERCANTILE EXCHANGE                                               Code-299741
Commitments of Traders - Futures Only, July 03, 2017
```

Find the contract definition based on the description in the file

http://www.cmegroup.com/trading/fx/g10/euro-fx-british-pound_contract_specifications.html

And look up what the details are based on the descriptive data given.  Here, the name and the contract basket match between the report and the spec I linked to.

**EDIT:**

For the new report you've edited, the proper contract is

http://www.cmegroup.com/trading/fx/g10/euro-fx_contract_specifications.html

Which as the contract definition specifies, is basically the currency pair `EUR/USD`, which you get from looking at the contract spec, and the rulebook linked from there

http://www.cmegroup.com/rulebook/CME/III/250/261/261.pdf

There is no USD section of the report because this is a report of listed futures contracts - to get the market's activity in a currency pair, you just look at the futures contract for that pair.

In your example, the correct wording is

> You can see that the non-commercial investors have 185,925 long positions
>   while they only hold 108,461 short positions in EUR/USD

And, I would bet you can't forecast which way a currency pair is heading using these reports, for the same reason there aren't hundred dollar bills on the street.

Comment: I apologize previously I have posted the wrong report. Now I have edited and replaced the correct report with single currency (instead of cross currency). Further, I read the `specification` you posted of `cmegroup.com`, but still I can't understand what it says. Can you elaborate a little bit how that `COT report` and `contract specifications` related to each other and what can we interpret based on those data? How can we forecast which way a currency pair is heading (eg:EUR/USD)? using those `COT` reports and `contract specifications`

Comment: Should we have to get individual `COT reports` of `Euro` and `USD` seperately and then divide the `Long positions of Euro` by the `Long positions of USD`? and do the same to the positions of previous data and compare each other? is that a correct method to check the direction of currency pair of `EURUSD`?